Dynamically populating drodpdown in the settings pane of a custom power bi visual
I'm developing a custom visual for Power BI, and I want to display a dropdown in the settings pane, which needs to be dynamically populated, since I want the values to be dependent on other configurations.
The problem is that dropdowns are statically declared in the capabilities.json file, e.g.
    "dropdownValuesMapping": {
      "displayName": "Dropdown",
      "type": {
        "enumeration": [
          {
            "displayName": "Dropdown display 1",
            "value": "value1"
          },
          {
            "displayName": "Dropdown display 2",
            "value": "value2"
          },
          {
            "displayName": "Dropdown display 3",
            "value": "value3"
          },
          {
            "displayName": "Dropdown display 4",
            "value": "value4"
          }
        ]
      }
    }, 

I found no way to access the displayName values, or the entire enumeration configuration.
I would expect some way of being able to dynamically change the dropdown.
An alternative would be to be able to add my own react component to the settings pane, but I also don't know how to do that
